# Couldn't pair with XXX because of an incorrect PIN or passkey

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing, headset

I'm trying to connect a bluetooth headset to my phone ( Poco X3 Pro ) but I end up with this error instead.

Things that I have tried:

- Rebooting device
- Killing bluetooth app and clearing all of its data ( user settings and cache )
- Cleared cache from the Connectivity settings ( clears wifi, bluetooth etc )
- Tried to download a Bluetooth app from the Playstore and connect through it, same error
- Tried to manually "Forget" or "Disconnect" the device from the Bluetooth settings, but the android version doesn't even have these buttons ( long pressing or swiping on the device doesn't do anything )

Is there some sort of incompatibility between the devices where they just would not get along?

When I put the headset into pairing mode ( holding its button for a few seconds ) and I click on "Pair" from my phone, it hangs for around 5-7 seconds and then displays the error from the title.

The headset connects just fine to my older phone and doesn't require any additional inputs, apart for OS permissions.

Answer (score 1):

So, none of the things mentioned above worked for me.

I ended up holding the connectivity button for like 10 seconds until it powered off and then held it for longer than the manual recommended, then it connected properly.

On two other phones it didn't matter how I turned it on, it would connect instantly, but on mine it didn't for some reason.